# Pass unique event id in url for diffrent event in codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter-2, cname

I am developing an event management system using PHP Codeigniter and MySQL where I am not sure how i can solve below issues

**ISSUE 1**

I want to make URL for back end like

```
www.event-backend.com/event/EVENt_ID (for dashboard)
www.event-backend.com/event/EVENt_ID/registration
www.event-backend.com/event/EVENt_ID/travel
and so on
```

and by changing the **EVENT_ID**  i can open different event

But in codeigniter how I can do it, second param will be a method of controller, i need it dynamic. what will be the routing ?

**ISSUE 2**

I want to people can access event website (which is unique for every event) by typing

```
  www.somedomain.com  
     which will be pointing at 
  www.event-backend.com/website/EVENt_ID
```

**Issue 2 can be solved with some CNAME record, but I don't know how to do it**

Please help

Answer (score 0):

U can use inner redirect for this purpose. For example like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^event/(.*)$ /event/controller/$1
```

Comment: Thanks Stas, is there any way i can accomplish same without htaccess, using codeigniter router or controller